# Are food regulations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I might have dietary restrictions that affect my choice of ingredients.  Many countries have regulatory bodies (like the FDA in America) that encourage or require food vendors to respect these restrictions (e.g. listing ingredients, disclaiming possible cross-contamination between common allergens).

**Because the presence of food regulations can affect how I select ingredients, what kinds questions about food regulations (if any) are on topic for Seasoned Advice?**

Comment: It's actually a lot simpler for us to say if something is specifically allowed or not allowed... rather than us needing to guess what you might mean... so it might be easier for us to answer your question if you have specific examples of questions that you'd consider asking along with some details so that we can let you know if that would be OK here. :D

Comment: @Catija No specific questions in mind, but I'd like to avoid having to ask two when one will do.